# Reactor vs Coroutines: GlobalScope.launch vs Mono.subscribeOn(Schedulers.).subscribe()

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, reactor

Using kotlin in a spring-boot reactive application with netty server. I have a service that should launch an async operation. This operation should not block the original request processing (i.e. the reqeust handling should finish while the operation might keep running in its own life-cycle).

Coming from the Spring reactive perspective I can do this using Reactor:

```
Mono.fromRunnable<Unit> {
  runBlocking {
    // do other operation
  }
}
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
  .subscribe()
```

but I also could do something like this, using kotlin coroutines:

```
GlobalScope.launch { 
  withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // do other operation
  }
}
```

Both effectively schedule the operation on a different thread and fulfill the requirement of launching that async operation. But what is the trade-off here? Is there any arguments why one of them is "better"?

My initial thought is that the "Reactor-approach" creates new threads while the coroutine approach might be more performant?

Comment: If your background operation is not suspending and you just need a fire and forget  behavior, then I guess it doesn't really make too much difference if you use Reactor, GlobalScope, your own executor with a thread pool or even if you just start a thread manually. Probably the only difference is that thread pools re-use threads and they can optionally limit parallelism if needed, so they are generally preferable. However, if you don't launch this operation too frequently (do you?), it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @broot, I've never used Reactor, but surely it is using thread pools anyway for its Schedulers?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I'm also not familiar with Reactor. What I meant was if we don't intend to use any features specific to coroutines or Reactor (I believe) and we use these frameworks simply as "executors" for some tasks, then I think they don't differ too much from each other and from other ways of executing async tasks. We effectively choose only between solutions based on bound thread pools or between starting a new thread per task and most frameworks can be configured to use both execution models anyway.

Comment: The async operation is suspending and it is launched frequently: the original request stores an event, the background operation handles the event and triggers new events in the system.

Comment: Thinking more about the actual use case it is probably inadequate to trigger the handler in that way. A more robust approach wrt to failover and more predictable approach wrt resource consumption is to schedule a service which checks if new events were stored and then handles them (instead of creating an in memory handler per request limited by a potential thread pool).